# Remove version information from maven generated war file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, tomcat, maven

I am trying to automate the deployment of war files that are generated by our build server using maven. I need to be able to extract the project name from the war filename so I can rename the file before deploying it. (Because tomcat uses the filename as the default context path and I don't want the version to be in there)

The filenames are usually in the form `projectname-version`. e.g:

```
myproject-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.war
my-better-project-1.2.3-RELEASE.war
my-fancy-project-1.2.3.war
```

- *SNAPSHOT* or *RELEASE* may or may not be included in the filename.
- One tricky part is to extract the project name when the project name includes dashes.

The result should be the project name without the version information:

```
myproject
my-better-project
my-fancy-project
```

How can I achieve this using bash and sed (or only bash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/-[0-9]\+.*//' file
```

Output:

```
myproject
my-better-project
my-fancy-project
```

---

With bash:

```
while read -r string; do
  [[ $string =~ (-[0-9]+.*) ]] && echo "${string%${BASH_REMATCH[1]*}}"
done < file
```

---

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '.*(?=-[0-9]+.*)' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using the sed solution for now:

    CONTEXT_PATH=`echo $1 | sed 's/-[0-9]\+.*//'`

Comment: or `CONTEXT_PATH=$(sed 's/-[0-9]\+.*//' <<< "$1")`